# JPA Criteria api function with double parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm stuck with this problem and after searching through the web for 2 days you are my last hope :p

I'm using JPA criteria api to construct my query. Everything works fine except when I want to add some sql function to the mix.

This is what I do to use sql function :

`Expression makePoint = criteriaBuilder.function("ST_MakePoint", Geometry.class, criteriaBuilder.parameter(double.class, "lat"), criteriaBuilder.parameter(double.class, "lng"));
Expression distanceSphere = criteriaBuilder.function("ST_Distance_Sphere", double.class, place.get("coordinates"), makePoint);
expression = criteriaBuilder.and(expression, criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(distanceSphere, radius));
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(expression);`

the declaration works fine, but when I set the parameters :

`session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter("lat",lat)`

I have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named parameter [lat] type mismatch; expecting [double] but found [Double]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.ExplicitParameterInfo.validateBindValue(ExplicitParameterInfo.java:70)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:467)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:57)
at co.sumwhere.api.communities.communitiesToPlaces.CommunitiesToPlaces.researchMultiple(CommunitiesToPlaces.java:207)
at co.sumwhere.api.places.PlacesController.getPlaces(PlacesController.java:356)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I even try to set the parameter with :

`double lat = 12.56;
double lat = Double.parseDouble("12.552");`

Nothing is working :(

Comment: Actually it's autoboxing at play here, Can you change the type from double.class to Double.class in criteriaBuilder.parameter() method.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the type from

> criteriaBuilder.parameter(**double.class**, "lat"),

to

> criteriaBuilder.parameter(**Double.class**, "lat"),

should work for you. For further reading [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).
Also run the following sample for understanding the exception you see.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Main {

      public static  void main(String args[]) {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        double var = 1022.222;
        list.add(var);
        // Notice that the double is autoboxed to Double type.
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass());
        System.out.println(double.class);
        // System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass().equals(double.class));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I already try, if I put Double, the function is not recognize in my database, and in sql you can only put "double precision".

Comment: Can you try using the setDouble method in the original code snippet posted in your question, so **session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter("lat",lat)** becomes **session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setDouble("lat", 123.00d)**. Refer the javadocs for more details. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setDouble(java.lang.String, double)